# Read content in HTML div tag with PHP

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Currently I have a snippet of code that looks like this:

```
    echo '<div id="content">';
    echo '<b>Results:<br></b>';
    echo '<div style="margin-right: 230px; margin-top: -20px;"><center><a href="http://clubpenguincheatsnow.com/tools/itemdatabase/"><b>Back</b></a><center></div>';
    $string = explode('<br>', $string);
    foreach ($string as $row) {
        preg_match('/^(.+)\s=\s(\d+)\s=\s(\D+)\s=\s(\d+)/', trim($row), $matches);
        if (preg_match("/$query/i", "$matches[1]")) {
            echo "<a href='http://clubpenguincheatsnow.com/tools/itemdatabase/info.php?id=$matches[2]'>";
            echo $matches[1];
            echo "</a><br>";
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

As you can see I have the div tags at the top and bottom `echo '<div id="content">';` `echo '</div>';`. What I want to do is my PHP code to scan the output that is between the two tags, and if the text `<b>Results:<br></b><div style="margin-right: 230px; margin-top: -20px;"><center><a href="http://clubpenguincheatsnow.com/tools/itemdatabase/"><b>Back</b></a><center></div>` is between the tags I want my code to output "Test." Any help regarding my problem would be very helpful!

Comment: Use a DOM parser to handle HTML, not regex!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for getting data from HTML.

Answer (score -1):

If you feel comfortable with Regex, you can use it when the page remains pretty much static. [This](http://www.txt2re.com) site can help you build regex queries. Otherwise, try and use Simple HTML DOM wherever possible as mentioned above. You'll have less chance of getting errors.